# Copying files multiple times to different destination folders

Tags: file, copy, inno-setup

I want to deploy a plugin for Autodesk 3ds Max with an Inno-Setup. If the end user has 3ds Max installed multiple times (in different folders) for having different languages (3ds Max isnt multilingual) I want the setup to copy the plugin-files to the several 3ds Max folders, but without copying the [Files] Source: "plugin.dll" DestDir: "..." . Can it be done programmatically with the pascal scripting, that the files are copied again but always with changing destination folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you want multiple `[Files]` entries? They will only be included in the setup once.

If you want to copy them in `[Code]`, you can use the `FileCopy()` function in either the AfterInstall handler function for the file, or the `CurStepChanged(ssPostInstall)` event function.

Note that if you install them manually, you lose all automatic reference counting, registration, and uninstall handling, all of which you'll need to replicate in code.

Comment: Thank you, I will go with the multiple entries in [Files]. I just wanted to avoid it as it makes the whole installer code confusing and harder to maintain in case of changes. But we will merge the installer-files to one dll and so have less entries.